# Splitting a matrix into quadrants according to the current position

Tags: c#

I want to split a matrix into quadrants, upper and bottom left and right, according to the current position. Here is an example(to avoid writing T/U, for example, I placed the different characters with top and left priority, but they do overlap):

```
o T T U o o o 
B T X U L L L
B B B L L L L 
B B B L L L L 
o o L L L L L 
o o L L L L L
```

X is the central element. o is an element not included in any of the quadrants, T is top left, U is top right, B is lower left and L is lower right, I hope you get the idea. My solution includes checking in which quadrant of the matrix the starting position is, and then making the quadrants accordingly, which makes a total of 4 cases each with 4 quadrants = 16. I hope there's a better way, so can you please help me with this? I'm writing the program in C#, but pseudocode is fine.

Comment: If an element is on the same row with central element, would it be part of top quadrant, upper quadrant, or both(, or neither)?

Comment: Both, as I've said they overlap

Comment: How is the matrix elements indexed? like in Cartesian from negative to positive or do we use only the 1st quadrant (`0` or `1`) to (`n` or `n-1`)?

Comment: It's indexed from zero to n-1.If it matters the maximum size is 15x15, but the X element can be anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the different quadrant of cartesian system through their respective property.

```
public class Matrix<T>
{
    public T[,] Elements { get; private set; }
    public int Size { get; private set; }
    public Point CentralPoint { get; set; }

    public T this [int y, int x]
    {
        get { return Elements[y, x]; }
        set { Elements[y, x] = value; }
    }

    public Matrix(int size)
    {
        this.Size = size;
        this.Elements = new T[Size, Size];
    }

    public T[,] FirstQuadrant { get { return FromCentralTo(Size - 1, 0); } }
    public T[,] SecondQuadrant { get { return FromCentralTo(0, 0); } }
    public T[,] ThirdQuadrant { get { return FromCentralTo(0, Size - 1); } }
    public T[,] FourthQuadrant { get { return FromCentralTo(Size - 1 , Size - 1); } }

    private T[,] FromCentralTo(int x1, int y1, [CallerMemberName]string caller = "")
    {
        var translate = Math.Min(Math.Abs(CentralPoint.X - x1), Math.Abs(CentralPoint.Y - y1));

        //fix the p1, so this results in a square array
        if (Math.Abs(CentralPoint.X - x1) > translate)
            x1 = CentralPoint.X + translate * Math.Sign(x1 - CentralPoint.X);
        if (Math.Abs(CentralPoint.Y - y1) > translate)
            y1 = CentralPoint.Y + translate * Math.Sign(y1 - CentralPoint.Y);

        var size = translate + 1;
        var start = new Point(Math.Min(CentralPoint.Y, y1), Math.Min(CentralPoint.X, x1));

        var result = new T[size, size];
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
                result[y, x] = this[start.Y + y, start.X + x];

        return result;
    }
}

public struct Point
{
    public int X, Y;
    public Point(int y, int x) { this.X = x; this.Y = y; }
}
```

---

```
void Main()
{
    var matrix = new Matrix<int>(7);
    matrix.CentralPoint = new Point(1, 2);

    int i = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++)
            matrix[x, y] = i++;

    matrix.Elements.Dump("Matrix");
    matrix[matrix.CentralPoint.Y, matrix.CentralPoint.X].Dump("Central");
    matrix.FirstQuadrant.Dump("1");
    matrix.SecondQuadrant.Dump("2");
    matrix.ThirdQuadrant.Dump("3");
    matrix.FourthQuadrant.Dump("4");
}
```

The above code produce the following in LINQPad :

[image: result]

Comment: As I understand it, all matrices must be square. It seems your matrices `Top`, `Bottom`, etc. are not.

Comment: Oh, that's what you mean by `o` element.

Comment: I've fixed the solution to return only the perfect square quadrants.